# Retry AddOrUpdate With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an issue where two records with the same PK can run through my program within milliseconds of each other, causing a PK violation because Entity Framework checks if the row exists for the second record before the first one is sent through. I have a class that handles the `AddOrUpdate` and `SaveChanges` shown here:

```
 public async Task Process(NewEvent newEvent)
    {
        try
        {              
            _unitOfWork.UnitRepository.AddOrUpdate(newEvent);

            await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var innerException = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;

            if (ShouldRetry(innerException))
            {    
                numRetries++;

                Logger.Warning(innerException.Message);
                Logger.Warning($"Now attempting retry #{numRetries}");

                await Process(newEvent);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error($"An error occured attempting to process {newEvent.eventType}");
                throw;

            }
        }
    }
```

If the PK violation occurs it should catch the exception and retry the method, so that the check is run again and by then the first record should have went through. However, no matter how many retries I do (tried 20) it always fails the check. Am I not waiting long enough?

Sidenote, my interfaces are registered as Scoped and should dispose the UnitOfWork everytime.

Comment: I do not see any waiting. What is inside `ProcessUnit`?

Comment: Are you able to set up your table to have it's primary key automatically generated?

Comment: @PeterBons Edited it to match method name, sorry. Should be `Process` which is just retrying the method that calls to `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: @SamIam It works better without an auto generated PK so that when an event comes in, it contains the PK I am using so EF can recognize it, rather than having to do a query for the record if it used auto generated PK

Comment: I would at least wait a few milliseconds between retries.

Comment: @PeterBons Most guides I found use `thread.sleep` which did not sound like best practice for a production environment. Also, increasing the retries gives it plenty of time (seconds) and it still fails the check

Comment: Have you ever tried to wait minutes, I kind of doubt the mistake is what you believe it is. My guess would be, you can wait all eternatiy and the error wont go away, can you verify?

Comment: @RandRandom Completely agree. If records with same PK come within 100 milliseconds they fail, but anything longer and it works. I've waited up to a few seconds and still fail, so I believe EF is saving something in the state that is never reset when the method is called again.

Comment: Try a non-blocking `await Task.Delay(50);` (50 is number of milliseconds) Sure you can hammer your db with new requests but it will probably save some processing time.

Comment: What happens if you somehow use a new unitofwork in the retry to make sure no state is cached?

Comment: Maybe give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989575/2598770

Comment: A little off-topic: personally I find the following retry better - droped some stuff to reduce text ``Process(object arg) { Process(arg, 0) } private Process(object arg, int retryCounter) { if (retryCounter > 30) return; Process(arg, ++retryCounter); }``